# Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting not cater Workflow Service with DefinitionIdentity

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I am using WF4.5 and Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting. I defined DefinitionIdentity for my workflow service. When WorkflowServiceTestHost.Open is called, it will give the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: The persistence provider implementation
>   of InstanceStore doesn't support the command named
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentity.
>   Either choose a different provider, or ensure that this persistence
>   command isn't attempted.

It seems because Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting.Persistence.MemoryStore didn't cater CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentityCommand. Anyone implemented it? Thanks.

Comment: I have modified MemoryStore myself and WorkflowServiceTestHost.Open will not raise exception now.